# RegEx for a range of percentages with 2 decimal points

Tags: regex

I'd like to create a regular expression that matches any percentage figure from 12.50% to 100.00%. All percentages are displayed with 2 decimal places and a % sign (with no space between the numbers and the % sign)

Matches:

```
12.50%
17.77%
71.01%
```

Won't match:

```
9.09%
10.00%
12.49%
```

I found this site:
http://gamon.webfactional.com/regexnumericrangegenerator/

which generated this RegEx for whole numbers:
(1[2-9]|[2-9][0-9]|100)

but am not sure how to handle this with floating point numbers and the % sign.
Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an alternation using your pattern, only use `.00` for the 100% variant and have a separate alternative matching 12:50 till 12:99

```
\b(?:12\.[5-9][0-9]|(?:1[3-9]|[2-9][0-9])\.[0-9]{2}|100\.00)%
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XI2EDI/1)

Comment: Thanks - From the demo I can see it works but also matches 12.00% to 12.49% but I'd like to exclude them if possible and only match 12.50% to 100%

Comment: Thank you very much - this seems exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 0):

This is a relatively hard problem for regular expressions, and a very easy problem for anything that can parse numbers into decimal or floating point values and do simple comparisons on those values, e.g. `awk`:

```
/[0-9.]+%/ {
    if ($1 >= 12.5 || $1 <= 100.0) {
        print $1
    }
}
```

So, why do you want to use a regular expression?