# RegEx of percentage number with and without 2 decimal points

Tags: regex

I want to create a regular expression that matches any number from 98 to 100. That also includes 2 decimal points starting from .01 to .99.
The exact figure starts from (98 > 98.01 > 98.99 > 99 > 99.01 to 100). These numbers are mixed with and without decimals.

**Matches**: 98 > 98.01 > 98.99 > 99 > 99.01 to 100.

**Not Matches**: 97.**99**, 97.**98**, **97**, or any number below the above range.

Thanks for any help you can give.

tried to follow this article: [RegEx for a range of percentages with 2 decimal points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60469560/regex-for-a-range-of-percentages-with-2-decimal-points)

but it's not giving an output of what I need. it will somehow also match the last 2 decimal points as well. I only need it to match 98, 98.01, and not 97.98.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `99.1` nor `99.00` are allowed, you could do it with this regex:

```
^(?:100|9[89](?:\.(?:0[1-9]|[1-9]\d))?)$
```

On [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/57e0z9/1)

#### Explanation:

- `^` and `$` are end-of-string anchors, so that the whole input must match the pattern
- `(?:   )` is a way to set the scope of operators like `|` and `?`.
- `100` matches that literal number and is dealt with as a separate case
- `|` separates alternative patterns
- `9[89]` matches either `98` or `99`
- `\.` a literal point
- To match two digits except `00` as decimals:

  - `0[1-9]` is a zero followed by a non-zero digit
  - `[1-9]\d` is a non-zero digit followed by any digit.
- `?` makes the fractional part optional.

Comment: This is brilliant, thanks! However, let's say I want to mix this with some text at the beginning, for example, to match with: "Used disk space on /sybase/P40/sapdata1 (percentage): 99.34" > and the only keyword I need to match from this word is "Sybase" only. How do I add that on top of your regex?

Comment: That would be a new question. Feel free to post one and explain what the logic is to identify "sybase" (and also the number?).

Answer (score 0):

Regexes are probably not the best tool for this. But anyway something like this should work:

`(100|(9[8|9](\.\d{1,2})*))`

We either match `100` directly or `(9[8|9](\.\d{1,2})*)`
This match a 9 followed either by a 9 or 8 which can be optionnally (the `*` character) by a dot and one or two decimals.

Comment: i've tried this, but somehow it will also match with the last decimal number (e.g. 97.99, 94.97, etc..) Which I do not want it. The match should be from the 1st two decimal numbers (e.g. 99.97, 99, 98, 98.99, etc..). In overall, it should match the number starting from 98, 98.01 until 99.99, 100 only! Anyway, thanks!